# HttpPut methods do not support parameter type of [user defined type]

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, compile-error

I'm at a loss. This class already compiled, was deployed, and has been working fine in production for over a year. Upon updating it, I'm now getting:

> HttpPut methods do not support parameter type of MyUserDefinedType

The @HttpPut method in the existing production code is:

```
@HttpPut
global static void activateContact(MyUserDefinedType user) {
    MyServiceClass service = new MyServiceClass( new List<MyUserDefinedType>{ user } );
    service.activateContacts();
}
```

I updated it to:

```
@HttpPut
global static void activateContact(MyUserDefinedType user) {
    MyServiceClass service = new MyServiceClass( new List<MyUserDefinedType>{ user } );

    try {
        service.activateContacts();
    }
    catch(MyUserDefinedType.MyUserException e) {
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The changes to MyUserDefinedType were to add a method to validate the parameter values and I added the inner exception class MyUserException (which is thrown in the validation method). I tried removing the inner exception class to a top-level class, but that didn't change anything.

I don't know what would be causing it to suddenly be an invalid user-defined type for an Http Put annotation.

EDIT:

Turns out, I had added another User-Defined Type as a member variable of MyUserDefinedType, which isn't allowed within an HttpPut parameter. I resolved the issue by making it `transient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Apex REST documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) you are restricted to certain types of parameter values:

These return and parameter types are allowed:

- [Apex primitives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm) (excluding sObject and Blob).
- sObjects
- Lists or maps of Apex primitives or sObjects (only maps with String keys are
  supported).
- User-defined types that contain member variables of the
  types listed above.

You didn't post the definition of your `MyUserDefinedType` class, but I'm guessing that `MyUserException` is extended from type `Exception`, which isn't a primitive nor one of the allowed serializable types.

Your best bet for working around this is to remove the exception from `MyUserDefinedType` and place it outside this class which is attempting to be serialized / deserialized as a parameter.

Comment: That was my initial though too, but I had also tried moving the Exception inner class out and it didn't resolve the issue. But your reply got me thinking about other disallowed member types and I did add another user-defined member variable to MyUserDefinedType. Once I made it `transient`, it all compiled fine. Thanks!